# Update JSON object in a ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-callback, jquery-post

I initialize my JSON object like this:

`var car = {"model":"honda","make":""}`

I have an ajax call to update the make:

```
function updateCarModel(id) {

$.ajax({
    url: '/Car/UpdateModel',
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify( id: id)

    success: function (data) {

                var localClientStorage = window.localStorage;

                var carObject = localClientStorage.getItem("car");

                carObject = JSON.parse(carObject );

                carObject.model = data.Car.Model;


                localClientStorage.setItem("car", JSON.stringify(carObject));
        } 
});
};
```

When I inspect the carObject in the chrome console, it shows the original object, not the updated one with the model.  I did check to see if `data.Car.Model` has a value of civic and it does.

Comment: How/when are you inspecting the carObject?

Comment: Why _data: JSON.stringify({ id: id})_ instead of _data: {"id": id}_?

Comment: did your ajax run properly?
no error?
try console inside you ajax response

Comment: maybe there's something wrong with your ajax response or error

Comment: @JimmyAdaro - Sorry typo. fixed.

Comment: @NewbeeDev - No errors.

Comment: @MattiPrice - In the chrome console, I am typing carObject and hitting enter.  When I do this, I see the original object I created with a make, but a blank model. I have script tag with an id of carObject where I store the JSON object, but it looks like it is retrieving my original non-updated value when I type in carObject.

Comment: `carObject` only exists in the context of the success function call and would be destroyed after. If you aren't setting a breakpoint inside that url, you are getting some other object that you've named `carObject` and that's why. Try using the dev console and going to the "application" tab and lookin in the local storage for the object you changed.

Comment: did you try to console the response?

Comment: @MattiPrice -  you are correct.  I am using the <script id="carObject"></script> to hold the value of the JSON object in the DOM.  The DOM is updated with model, so if that is the case and it is pulling the value from the DOM, why isn't it updated.  I checked the local storage and it does have the updated model as well.

Comment: @xaisoft adding "var" to a variable declaration scopes it locally so any changes to it aren't accessible outside the scope it is defined. You could try dropping the var from `var carObject = ` . I'm not familiar with setting a script object that way though.

Comment: @MattiPrice - I was thinking if I do something like this: `$('#carObj').text(JSON.stringify(carObj));`, it would work, but this updates the DOM with the correct object, but when I type in carObj in the console, I get the un-modified object

Comment: $('#carObj') is selecting your script tag element and changing it's text values.. I don't think that's what you really want to be doing.

Comment: @MattiPrice - How can I update the JSON object so that when I type in `carObj` in the chrome console, it shows the updated model?

Comment: Either load it from localstorage again, or instead of saving it to localstorage (or in addition to that), save it to the global variable you want to use.

Comment: @MattiPrice - I did try reading it back into that variable from localStorage, but that didn't work.  When you say save it to the global variable, where would I put this variable?

Comment: Try adding `var theCar;` just before `function updateCarModel(id) {` then after you set the local storage do `theCar = carObject;` and then in console access `theCar`